# Change data of Refs in v-for Loop - Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some problems with VueJs Change data of Refs in v-for Loop. Please help me.

My request: InitialitemStreamWidth and InitialitemStreamHeight is size of image. I want if

```
InitialitemStreamWidth > InitialitemStreamHeight
```

my image class will be `fit_width` and on the other hand is `fit_height`

My components:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, i) in user.photostream" :key="i">
      <picture class="fit_image">
        <img :class="{'fit_width' : fit_choice === 'Width', 'fit_height' : fit_choice === 'Height'}" :ref="'imageStream_' + item.id" :src="item.image"/>
      </picture>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      fit_choice: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.itemclass()
  },
  methods: {
    itemclass: function () {
      for (var item of this.user.photostream) {
        var InitialitemStreamWidth = this.$refs['imageStream_' + item.id][0].clientWidth
        var InitialitemStreamHeight = this.$refs['imageStream_' + item.id][0].clientHeight
        if (InitialitemStreamWidth > InitialitemStreamHeight) {
            this.fit_choice = 'Width'
        } else if (InitialitemStreamWidth <= InitialitemStreamHeight) {
            this.fit_choice = 'Height'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Error: fit_choice in data is not dynamic, it just fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you should init your `fit_choice` variable ('Width' or 'Height')

And if there will be a problem with your class expression in your template 
try this:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, i) in user.photostream" :key="i">
      <picture class="fit_image">
        <img v-if="fit_choice === 'Width'" class="class="fit_width" :ref="'imageStream_' + item.id" :src="item.image"/>
        <img v-else class="fit_height" :ref="'imageStream_' + item.id" :src="item.image"/>
      </picture>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

I have not tried, but I think you will understand the concept.

I hope it helps ;)

**UPDATE:**

I see In that case, you should change the `fit_choice` variable, to an array.

and then the method should be:

```
  for (var item of this.user.photostream) {
    var InitialitemStreamWidth = this.$refs['imageStream_' + item.id][0].clientWidth
    var InitialitemStreamHeight = this.$refs['imageStream_' + item.id][0].clientHeight
    if (InitialitemStreamWidth > InitialitemStreamHeight) {
        this.fit_choice.push('Width')
    } else if (InitialitemStreamWidth <= InitialitemStreamHeight) {
        this.fit_choice.push('Height')
    }
  }
```

then.. you have each class of each photo. After that your template should be:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, i) in user.photostream" :key="i">
      <picture class="fit_image">
        <img :class="{fit_choice[i]}" :ref="'imageStream_' + item.id" :src="item.image"/>
      </picture>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

(syntax can be bad, but I hope you can understand the concept of my new idea. :) )

Comment: Thank you Laki but you misunderstood my issues. I have issue with get `fit_choice` dynamic data. `itemclass` function just returns `itemclass='Width'` or `itemclass='Height'` and use it for ALL IMAGE CLASS IN LOOP V-FOR. I want fit_choice is a dynamic variable!!

Comment: I enclosed photo. Hope you understand!

Comment: Hi! I updated my answer, i hope that can help you. :)